# c# MVC & Visual Studio 2015: Azure Storage Blob upload file: I get MissingMethodException, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to upload a file in Azure Storage. Therefore, i have already created the function, that should upload the file. The azure storage is created and a container is also created:

```
public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            string accountName = "blabla";
            string accountKey = "blabla;

//get the name of the file
            string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            try
            {
                StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
                CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

                CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer = client.GetContainerReference("blabla");
                sampleContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("ExampleFile");

                using (Stream datei = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
                {
                    blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(datei);
                }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
        }
```

My view, where i have the button for upload looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

There are much more functions, models and views in my project, but only this doesn't work. Every time I run my web application, select the file that i want to upload and klick on the button 'Upload' I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

In the 'stack' part there is something like this:

> MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.d__3.MoveNext()
>   .....
>   .....

...and many others.

What is wrong with my code? Why I cannot upload a file?

Comment: Quick look it seems you may be missing an "await" before the line: blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(datei);

Comment: Agreed, you should be `await`ing the async calls, but do not use `.Result`, especially in Asp.Net. Also you will have to use `async` in your method signature.

Comment: Do you know what line it is failing on?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? Google your error, some things come up.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answers.

I changed now the input parameter to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile file.

I dont get the error anymore. But now he returns me every time to the Create view, so there must be somewhere an exception in the code.....

Comment: Ah, it's working now. I have it. Thank you ;)